# MS Project 2016 VBA Assignment UniqueID not matching screen

Tags: vba, ms-project

I have a simple task, with a single assignment. In the Task Usage view I am showing the UniqueID column, which gives the Assignment Unique ID as 1048577.

Then I run the following sample code to check that assignment ID:

```
Sub CheckAssignments()
    Dim oldTsks As Tasks
    Dim wrdAss As Assignment
    Dim wrdAss2 As Assignment

    Set prj = ActiveProject


    Set oldTsks = ActiveSelection.Tasks

    For Each t In oldTsks
        Debug.Print "Task ID: " & t.ID & " Task UID: " & t.UniqueID & " Task Name: " & t.Name & " Assignment Count: " & t.Assignments.Count
        For Each a In t.Assignments
            Debug.Print "   Assignment UID is: " & a.UniqueID
            Debug.Print "   Assignment Resource is: " & a.ResourceUniqueID & " - " & a.ResourceName
            Debug.Print "   Assignment Index is: " & a.Index
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

When I run this (making sure to select the correct task), I get the following result set:

```
Task ID: 1 Task UID: 1 Task Name: New Task Assignment Count: 1
   Assignment UID is: 2097153
   Assignment Resource is: 1 - Fred
   Assignment Index is: 1
```

Question: Where is the 2097153 coming from???? And why can't I find 1048577 when iterating through the Assignments collection?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a known bug in MS Project. Apparently when looping through the assignments object the ID is off by 2^20, or 1,048,576. You can reference the assignment using either number, but the real problem is that the Assignments collection isn't stable when iterating by object. The workaround I ended up using is to use the Assignments.Count property and iterate from 1 to the Count, instead of using For Each a in Assignments.